# Some items in SVG drawing are showing up as question marks in various Mac OS apps, and Inkscape

Tags: vector, svg, export, adobe-flash

I have an SVG drawing that has some little trees in one section of it.

Up until recently it was all fine, but the latest version of it that was emailed to me recently has a really weird problem.

Here's what I see in Chrome, Apple Quicklook and Inkscape respectively:

[image: Chrome]

[image: Quicklook]

[image]

What makes it **really weird** is that I can actually see the trees in my Mac Mail client! See screen capture (small because that's all I can see in the Mail message):

[image]

This is the first time this has happened and I have asked the artist to send another export just in case (exported from an .fla file by the way).

Answer (score 3):

That happens because the tree images aren't in the same folder that the SVG resides, there are two ways that you can solve it:

1. Copying the necesary files to the same folder that the SVG resides.
2. Embed the image in the SVG file (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249664/does-svg-support-embedding-of-bitmap-images)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But any idea why they are still visible in my Mac Mail client message pane?

Comment: @Drewdavid: It can be that the tree images are in some folder that your mail client searches.

Comment: You should open the SVG file with a text editor and search for the `<image>` tag and see the `xlink:href` attribute, it will help you to find where are located the images and where you have to put it.

Comment: Strange, I'm not aware of any extra folders existing, and it always worked before this last version of the drawing was sent to me. Well I have emailed the artist so we'll see what they are able to figure out! Thanks for the answers, I have referenced this question in my correspondence with the artist. If I have a resolution I will post it or mark as correct if this helps! :)